# Print specific values from a multi-value element array in python

Tags: python, arrays, data-structures, python-3.6

In python 3, I am trying to create an `array` of elements, where each element consists of two values. These values are not really `key-value` pairs because they are equally related to each other, meaning `value` 1 could be the `key` for `value` two, just as `value` two could be the `key` to `value` one and so I didn't think a `dictionary` was appropriate.

```
my_list = [ (VALUE1, OFFSET1), (VALUE2, OFFSET2) ]

def printList(list):
    for item in list:
        print(item)
```

How could I collect the `VALUE` and `OFFSET` `"values"` separately? Such as

```
theValue  = list[0].VALUE
theOffset = list[0].OFFSET
```

I'm thinking an `array` of structs perhaps?

Comment: Are you looking to explicitly use the *dot notation* as you are using to access the elements per `list[0].VALUE` and `list[0].OFFSET`?

Comment: The dot notation is the only way I know to specifically refer to an an exact value.. the dot notation is not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def printList(my_list):
    for item in my_list:
        print('Value ', item[0])
        print('Offset ', item[1])
```

The for loop iterates through `my_list`. Each element in the loop is received as tuple like `(VALUE, OFFSET)` in the variable item. So `item[0]` is `VALUE` and `item[1]` is `OFFSET`. And we print it.

Comment: Can you explain your answer please.

Comment: @idjaw: The for loop iterates through my_list. Each element in the loop is received as tuple like (VALUE, OFFSET) in the variable item. So item[0] is VALUE and item[1] is OFFSET. And we print it.

Comment: Edit your answer to include this explanation so readers understand what it is you are providing as an answer.

Comment: I chose this because it shows how to extract both values from a given element number easily.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip`, which transposes the list and collects elements at the same position to one element in the result:

```
value, offset = zip(*my_list)

value
#('VALUE1', 'VALUE2')

offset
#('OFFSET1', 'OFFSET2')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll do this like:

```
my_list = [ ("VALUE1", "OFFSET1"), ("VALUE2", "OFFSET2") ]

def printList(my_llst):
  values = []
  ofts = []
  for item in my_llst:
      values.append(item[0])
      ofts.append(item[1])
  return (values,ofts)
```

> (['VALUE1', 'VALUE2'], ['OFFSET1', 'OFFSET2'])

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a `list` of `tuples`, instead of:

```
theValue  = list[0].VALUE
theOffset = list[0].OFFSET
```

You can use:

```
theValue = list[0][0]
theOffset = list[0][1]
```

So in your `for-loop`:

```
def printList(list):
    for item in list:
        print('VALUE: {}'.format(item[0]))
        print('OFFSET: {}'.format(item[1]))
```

If you want to get all values in `list` and offsets in a separate `list`, you can use `list-comprehension`:

```
values = [x[0] for x in list]
offsets = [x[1] for x in list]
```

One more important thing, **AVOID** using `built-in` functions like `list` as variables, use something else instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
theValue  = [value[0] for value in my_list] 
theOffset = [offset[0] for value in offset]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `namedtuple` can help you.

```
from collections import namedtuple

Element = namedtuple("Element", ["value", "offset"])

element_list = []

for value, offset in my_list:

    element_list.append(Element(value, offset))

for element in element_list:

    print element.value, element.offset
```

If you want to get all values and offsets separately, you can use numpy to transform my_list to `numpy.array` which is a 2d array.

```
import numpy as np

2d_array = np.array(my_list)

values = 2d_array[:, 0]
offsets = 2d_array[:, 1]
```